# Does facebook analytics for apps allow me to track mobile app user insights, even without the facebook login?

Tags: facebook, sdk, facebook-analytics

I'm working on building an IOS/android app and I'm wondering how i can use Facebook Analytics for apps.

There is no social login for the app, but i would like to use in-app events to retarget users of the app as they browse facebook owned platforms, even though they have not used facebook to sign in etc on the IOS/Android app.

Can this be done by implementing the Facebook analytics SDK?

I appreciate that i'm not a developer, so this question may yet prove to be totally misinformed.

Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow is platform for developers only - you are required to try stuff before asking. questions like "can i do xy" are usually too broad here.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Analytics doesn't acquire Facebook login. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/faqs/#faq_529032737286063

You can send app events with Facebook Analytics that you can use to view reports in Facebook Analytics as well as use for tracking conversions from Facebook ads and building remarketing audiences (custom audiences) in Facebook ads.

iOS App Events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios

Android App Events: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android